# Sumar una columna usando una variable en SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

Estoy sumando una columna de mi cosulta:

```
SELECT SEGMENTO, ESTATUS, CONCEPTO, SUM([ENE-20]) AS [ENE-20]
FROM Tabla
GROUP BY CONCEPTO, ESTATUS, SEGMENTO
```

Necesito hacer el mismo proceso solo que la suma tiene que ser una variable, esto es lo que tengo:

```
DECLARE @TEST NVARCHAR(10)
SET @TEST = '[ENE-20]'

SELECT SEGMENTO, ESTATUS, CONCEPTO, SUM(@TEST) AS [ENE-20]
FROM Tabla
GROUP BY CONCEPTO, ESTATUS, SEGMENTO
```

Pero me muestra el siguiente error:

> Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: Necesitas usar una sql dinamica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que hacer un sql dinamico.

Este debe funcionarte:

```sql
DECLARE @TEST AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR (MAX)
SET @TEST = 'NOMBRE_DE_LA_COLUMNA_A_SUMAR'

SET @query = 'SELECT SEGMENTO, ESTATUS, CONCEPTO, SUM('+@TEST+') AS COMO_TU_QUIERAS
FROM Tabla GROUP BY CONCEPTO, ESTATUS, SEGMENTO'

execute(@query)
```

Te dejo esta pagina donde viene un poco más y a mí me ayudo bastante hace tiempo
https://ing-sistemas.com/2017/03/24/sql-dinamico-en-transact-sql/

Comment: Enlace en SO en inglés (por si el enlace indicado muere algún día...) [SO original](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108465/simple-dynamic-tsql-query-syntax)

Comment: Enlace a la documentación de MS: [documentación MS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)